# how to add the spendTime of the operation when use CompletableFuture whenComplete

Tags: java, completable-future

The demo code is like this:

```
@Test
public void testOrder2() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecInfo execInfo = new ExecInfo();
    CompletableFuture<Integer> dataFutrue = testOrderFunc(execInfo);
    dataFutrue.handle((dataRet,err) -> {
        System.out.println("test" + execInfo.cost);
        return null;
    });
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}

class ExecInfo {
    long cost=0;
}

private CompletableFuture<Integer> testOrderFunc(ExecInfo execInfo) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    CompletableFuture<Integer> ret = new CompletableFuture<>();

    ret.whenComplete((data, error) -> {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long spend = end-start;
        execInfo.cost = spend;
        System.out.println("whenComplete 1.cost:" + execInfo.cost);
    }) ;

    invoke2(ret);
    //may be has other operation about ret. if ret is not completed.
    return ret;
}

private void invoke2(CompletableFuture<Integer> ret) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("1s complete");
        ret.complete(1);
    });
}
```

The result is :

- 1s complete
- test0
- whenComplete 1.cost:1050

It seems that whenCompete is like stack FILO.

How to get testOrderFunc cost time?
Thanks your answer.

Comment: It’s not recognizable what you want to measure. You have four `CompletableFuture` instances in your code. Do you want to measure, how much overhead you get from creating four completion stages around a single `sleep` call? Besides that, when the function passed to `handle` depends on the result of the action passed to `whenComplete`, you have to chain the `handle` call to the stage returned by `whenComplete`, though you shouldn’t pass results through side effects anyway (precisely to prevent such bugs).

Comment: sleep call is just like a RPC call which cost 1s. I want return the testOrderFunc 's cost  to the users. testOrderFunc function may has other logic to do such as retry, so I create the ret future here to return.

Comment: As said, you can fix the issue the simple way, by returning the future returned by `whenComplete` to the caller. But the structure as shown in the question, is questionable and likely have more errors. E.g. this code can’t detect failures, so which criteria is used to decide to make a retry?

Comment: yeah, i have returned whenComplete  to the caller now. may be this is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your access to `cost` has a dependency to the action that writes the value you should also chain it to the associated stage. E.g.

```java
private CompletableFuture<Integer> testOrderFunc(ExecInfo execInfo) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    CompletableFuture<Integer> ret = new CompletableFuture<>();

    CompletableFuture<Integer> finalStage = ret.whenComplete((data, error) -> {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long spend = end-start;
        execInfo.cost = spend;
        System.out.println("whenComplete 1.cost:" + execInfo.cost);
    }) ;

    invoke2(ret);
    // other stuff
    return finalStage;
}
```

But it’s preferable not to use side effects, precisely to prevent such dependency related bugs. An alternative would be

```java
@Test
public void testOrder2() {
    CompletableFuture<Long> executionTime = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<Integer> dataFuture = testOrderFunc(executionTime);
    CompletableFuture<Void> printTime = executionTime
        .thenAccept(nanos -> System.out.printf("test took %.1f ms%n", nanos * 1e-6));
    CompletableFuture.allOf(dataFuture, printTime).join();
}

private CompletableFuture<Integer> testOrderFunc(CompletableFuture<Long> timeTarget) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    CompletableFuture<Integer> ret = new CompletableFuture<>();
    ret.whenComplete((data, error) -> timeTarget.complete(System.nanoTime() - start));

    invoke2(ret);
    // other stuff
    return ret;
}

private void invoke2(CompletableFuture<Integer> ret) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        System.out.println("1s complete");
        ret.complete(1);
    });
}
```

This forces the caller to chain the consumer of the measured time to the right future. Further, callers not interested in the execution time can chain dependent evaluations to the data future, without creating a dependency to the time measurement.

It also allows the caller to do something like that instead:

```java
@Test
public void testOrder2() {
    CompletableFuture<Long> executionTime = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<Integer> dataFuture = testOrderFunc(executionTime);
    dataFuture.exceptionally(t -> null).thenCombine(executionTime,
        (result, nanos) -> System.out.printf("test completed with %s after %.1f ms%n",
            result == null? "an error": result, nanos * 1e-6)) .join();
    dataFuture.join(); // relay exceptions to caller, if any
}
```

---

Note that in general, to measure *elapsed time*, you should use the difference between two values returned by [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()), which will be immune against leap seconds, NTP updates or such alike.